How do I solve the error Protocol error (Runtime.addBinding): Cannot find execution context with given executionContextId?
I am trying to code a program in Node.js that uses puppeteer to click a button on a webpage that cause the browser to visit a new webpage and puppeteer has to click a button on the new page. Every time I run the code I get the error

Exception has occurred: ProtocolError: Protocol error (Runtime.addBinding): Cannot find execution context with given executionContextId.

When I set headless to false I see the code has no problem clicking the first button on the webpage but it encounters an error when trying to clicking the second one.


const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');

(async () => {
  const browser = await puppeteer.launch({ headless: false });
  const page = await browser.newPage();
  const buttonSelector = 'input.btn.ispSubHeader[value="Download All'; 
  try {
    // Step 1: Go to the initial page
    await page.goto(''https://isp.illinois.gov/Sor/disclaimer'', { waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 60000 });

    // Step 2: Trigger navigation to the new page
    await Promise.all([
      page.waitForNavigation({ waitUntil: 'networkidle2', timeout: 60000 }),
      page.click('button.btn.ispSubHeader[value="Agree')  
    ]);

    // Step 3: Wait for the new page to load
    await page.waitForSelector('body', { timeout: 60000 });

    // Step 4: Interact with the new page (e.g., click the button)
    
    await page.waitForSelector(buttonSelector, { timeout: 60000 });

    // Verify if the button is visible
    const buttonVisible = await page.evaluate((selector) => {
      const button = document.querySelector(selector);
      return button && button.offsetParent !== null;
    }, buttonSelector);

    if (buttonVisible) {
      // Click the button
      await page.click(buttonSelector);
      //  take a screenshot after clicking the button
      await page.screenshot({ path: 'after_click.png' });
      console.log('Button clicked successfully');
    } else {
      console.error('Button not visible or not found.');
    }

  } catch (error) {
    console.error('Error occurred:', error);

    //  take a screenshot if an error occurs
    await page.screenshot({ path: 'error_screenshot.png' });
  } finally {
    await browser.close();
  }
})();



Also, in Visual Studio Code, when I run the code, another window opens, called deferred.ts and that's where the error comes from.


/**
 * @license
 * Copyright 2024 Google Inc.
 * SPDX-License-Identifier: Apache-2.0
 */
import {TimeoutError} from '../common/Errors.js';

/**
 * @internal
 */
export interface DeferredOptions {
  message: string;
  timeout: number;
}

/**
 * Creates and returns a deferred object along with the resolve/reject functions.
 *
 * If the deferred has not been resolved/rejected within the `timeout` period,
 * the deferred gets resolves with a timeout error. `timeout` has to be greater than 0 or
 * it is ignored.
 *
 * @internal
 */
export class Deferred<T, V extends Error = Error> {
  static create<R, X extends Error = Error>(
    opts?: DeferredOptions
  ): Deferred<R, X> {
    return new Deferred<R, X>(opts);
  }

  static async race<R>(
    awaitables: Array<Promise<R> | Deferred<R>>
  ): Promise<R> {
    const deferredWithTimeout = new Set<Deferred<R>>();
    try {
      const promises = awaitables.map(value => {
        if (value instanceof Deferred) {
          if (value.#timeoutId) {
            deferredWithTimeout.add(value);
          }

          return value.valueOrThrow();
        }

        return value;
      });
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-restricted-syntax
      return await Promise.race(promises);
    } finally {
      for (const deferred of deferredWithTimeout) {
        // We need to stop the timeout else
        // Node.JS will keep running the event loop till the
        // timer executes
        deferred.reject(new Error('Timeout cleared'));
      }
    }
  }

  #isResolved = false;
  #isRejected = false;
  #value: T | V | TimeoutError | undefined;
  // SAFETY: This is ensured by #taskPromise.
  #resolve!: (value: void) => void;
  #taskPromise = new Promise<void>(resolve => {
    this.#resolve = resolve;
  });
  #timeoutId: ReturnType<typeof setTimeout> | undefined;
  #timeoutError: TimeoutError | undefined;

  constructor(opts?: DeferredOptions) {
    if (opts && opts.timeout > 0) {
      this.#timeoutError = new TimeoutError(opts.message);
      this.#timeoutId = setTimeout(() => {
        this.reject(this.#timeoutError!);
      }, opts.timeout);
    }
  }

  #finish(value: T | V | TimeoutError) {
    clearTimeout(this.#timeoutId);
    this.#value = value;
    this.#resolve();
  }

  resolve(value: T): void {
    if (this.#isRejected || this.#isResolved) {
      return;
    }
    this.#isResolved = true;
    this.#finish(value);
  }

  reject(error: V | TimeoutError): void {
    if (this.#isRejected || this.#isResolved) {
      return;
    }
    this.#isRejected = true;
    this.#finish(error);
  }

  resolved(): boolean {
    if (this.#isRejected) console.log('resolved anyway')
    return this.#isResolved;
  }

  finished(): boolean {
    return this.#isResolved || this.#isRejected;
  }
  
  value(): T | V | TimeoutError | undefined {
    return this.#value;
  }

  #promise: Promise<T> | undefined;
  valueOrThrow(): Promise<T> {
    if (!this.#promise) {
      this.#promise = (async () => {
        await this.#taskPromise;
        if (this.#isRejected) {   //this is where the error shows up
          throw this.#value;
        }
        return this.#value as T;
      })();
    }
    return this.#promise;
  }
}



Here is the stack trace.

at <instance_members_initializer> (C:\Users\adien\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\CallbackRegistry.js:93:14)
at new Callback (C:\Users\adien\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\CallbackRegistry.js:97:16)
at CallbackRegistry.create (C:\Users\adien\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\common\CallbackRegistry.js:22:26)
at Connection._rawSend (C:\Users\adien\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\Connection.js:80:26)
at CdpCDPSession.send (C:\Users\adien\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\CDPSession.js:66:33)
at IsolatedWorld.adoptHandle (C:\Users\adien\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\cdp\IsolatedWorld.js:219:44)
at CdpElementHandle. (C:\Users\adien\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\ElementHandle.js:245:105)
at CdpElementHandle. (C:\Users\adien\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\util\decorators.js:98:27)
at CdpFrame.$ (C:\Users\adien\node_modules\puppeteer-core\lib\cjs\puppeteer\api\Frame.js:366:35)
at process.processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5)


You can see the website in the code. It's https://isp.illinois.gov/Sor/disclaimer
